# Why do `ls /bin` and `ls -l /bin` print different files

Tags: shell

I'm new to shell and still practicing on it.
When I typed

```
ls /bin
```

The shell prints many files

```
'['                                   mousetweaks
 aa-enabled                           mscompress
 aa-exec                              msexpand
 aa-features-abi                      mt
 aconnect                             mt-gnu
..
```

But when I typed

```
ls -l /bin
```

I was expecting the same output file in long format, but it seems like the shell just gives me a soft link

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7  Sept  5 15:22 /bin -> usr/bin
```

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The POSIX specification for `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) says this:

> -l
>
> (The letter ell.) Do not follow symbolic links named as operands unless the **-H** or **-L** options are specified. Write out in long format (see the STDOUT section). Disable the **-C**, **-m**, and **-x** options.

If you want to change the behavior, in addition to the two options specified above, you can also put a trailing slash after the name (i.e., `/bin/` instead of `/bin`).